# Python- How to compare new value with previous value on for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

My function needs to find the character with the highest speed in a dictionary. Character name is the key and value is a tuple of statistics. Speed is index `6` of the value tuple. How do I compare the previous highest speed to the current value to see if it is higher? Once I get the speed, how can I take that character's types (index 1 and 2 in value tuple,) and return them as a list?

Example Data:

```
d={'spongebob':(1,'sponge','aquatic',4,5,6,70,6), 'patrick':(1,'star','fish',4,5,6,100,1)}
```

Patrick has the highest speed(100) and his types are `star` and `fish`. Should return [star,fish]

Here is my current code which doesn't work since I don't know how to compare previous and current:

```
def fastest_type(db):
    l=[]
    previous=0
    new=0
    make_list=[[k,v] for k,v in db.items()]
    for key,value in db.items():
        speed=value[6]
    return l_types.sort()
```

Comment: you compare previous with value[6] in the loop. if it's smaller than value[6], you set it to value[6] and save value in new. then return new[1:3] after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sorted` function can do this quite easily:

**Code:**

```
from operator import itemgetter

def fastest_type(db):
    fastest = sorted(db.values(), reverse=True, key=itemgetter(6))[0]
    return fastest[1], fastest[2]
```

This code sorts by key `6`, in reverse order so that the largest is first, and then set `fastest` to the first element of the sort.  Then it simply returns the two desired fields from fastest.

**Test Code:**

```
d = {
    'spongebob':(1,'sponge','aquatic',4,5,6,70,6),
    'patrick':(1,'star','fish',4,5,6,100,1)
}

print(fastest_type(d))
```

**Results:**

```
('star', 'fish')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you meant.

```
def fastest_type(db):
    speed = 0
    new = []
    for key,value in db.items():
       if speed < value[6]:
           speed = value[6]
           new = value[1:3]
    return list(new) # return list instead of tuple
```

Comment: This yields the following error on every test case: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'speed' referenced before assignment

Comment: @ocean.1234 sorry an error. previous = 0 should be speed = 0. copied from your code and failed to change it.

Comment: This is still failing all test cases. The list has the wrong types.

Comment: @ocean.1234 what do you mean by the wrong types? it returned a tuple with the value of 'star', 'fish' when i tested. it returned a tuple because the input contains tuples. if you need a list, you just change return new to return list(new).

Comment: I mean like type as in 'star' 'fish'. For instance it would return ('aquatic', 'sponge') but it needs to return ('star','fish')

Comment: I got ['star', 'fish'] when i tested it with your data.